# table doesnt fit into parent scrolled div while using position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my English.
I have an included php page which contain a table to be displayed as position:fixed;
but it appears always above the scrollbars and not included within the parent div.

[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rzpe.png)

water.php:

```
    <div id="waterDBDiv">
        <table id="titlesTable">
          <tr>
              <td>title</td>
              <td>title</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

       <table id="contentTable">
          <tr>
              <td>title</td>
              <td>title</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
```

included in index.php:

```
switch ($q) {
   case "Water":
   include("water.php");
   break;
}
```

CSS:

```
#waterDBDiv {
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
    }

#titlesTable {
    margin:50px 0 0 0 ;
    position:fixed;        
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position:fixed means,that element should be in a fixed position in html page.
so setting parent for it is not true (i think).
And about scrolls you can set `Z-index` for table.
Now you can set same `width` for table and it's parent

Comment: when I zet z-index for titles table to be bellow the content table it happens like this

Comment: OK you want that title table be on top always.you can set the content table within title table and set overflow for title table

Comment: exactly, this is what I want, but it didnt work with me, could you please help me with a sample of code?